# Testing express app with mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I have the following request that I need to test:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"content":{"value":"18.5", "date": "20120413"}}' 'http://SERVER:PORT/marks'
```

I'm using expressjs and mocha. I did not find the way to add some header and specify some json parameters in a mocha's request:

```
it('Checks creation of a new mark', function(done){
   request.post('http://SERVER:PORT/marks', function(err, response, body){
   // Some headers and parameters should be set in the request
   response.statusCode.should.equal(201);
  done();
});
```

});

The test below (GET request) works well though:

```
it('Checks existence of marks for user dummyuser', function(done){
  request.get('http://SERVER:PORT/user/dummyuser/marks', function(err, response, body){
    response.statusCode.should.equal(200);
    done();
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

The following works like a charm: (I though request what some kind of variable created by mocha).

```
 request(
  { method: 'POST'
  , uri: 'http://SERVER:PORT/marks'
  , headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' , 'accept': 'application/json' }
  , json: { "content":{"value":"18,5", "date": "2012-04-13"} }
  }
, function(err, response, body){
  response.statusCode.should.equal(201);
  done();
});
```

Comment: Are you using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)? If so, check out the documentation, it describes how to set headers and how to send data as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback). There is a great explaination of how to do a post with custom headers. One way of doing it which works for me could be the following.

```
var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 80,
  path: '/echo/200',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "X-Terminal-Id" : terminalId
  }
};
var data = ""
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    data += d;
  });
  res.on('end', function(err){
    //Check that data is as expected
    done(null, data)
  })
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(err) {}
  done(err) 
});
```